# Failed to execute 'set' on 'URLSearchParams': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set new parameter in URL

What I did is this

```
function setParamsTest(selector, category) {
    const url = new URL(window.location);
    url.searchParams.set(`${category}, ${selector}`);
    window.history.pushState({}, "", url);
    window.location.reload();
}


searchWithCategories('buttons' , 'maca')
```

I'm getting following error

```
Failed to execute 'set' on 'URLSearchParams': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.
```

Comment: url.searchParams.set(category,selector);

Answer (score 0):

Try removing string interpolation in set parameters. By gruping them with quotes, it interprets it as a single argument.

```
function setParamsTest(selector, category) {
    const url = new URL(window.location);
    url.searchParams.set(category, selector);
    window.history.pushState({}, "", url);
    window.location.reload();
}
```